# Strange behavior with adding directory with contents to root

Tags: git, directory, repository

We just added a directory with contents to the root of a git repo using 'git add .' and then 'git commit -m "message..."'. We then pushed it up to bitbucket. This is our typical workflow.

However, when another developer pulls the repo down that new directory comes up empty. And in bitbucket we are getting a strange file listing. See: http://sandbox.thecanarycollective.com/whiteboard/2012-02-24_103433.png

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a submodule. Somehow you (or perhaps your colleagues) made one.

> Submodules allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated 
>   subdirectory of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

I cannot find documentation about submodules for bitbucket, but github have a page related to them:

http://help.github.com/submodules/

Comment: thanks. we didn't realize there was a .git folder in that directory.